# Automate Task in PDF editor

Tags: pdf, automation, bots, editor, adobe

I am making PDF format digital planner. Now I have finished desining the pages and need to link each elements to required pages.

Example. I have a home icon on each page that I want to link to second page.

How Can I do that?

App I have for PDF editing - Foxit PDF editor & Adobe PDF editor DC

Comment: I do not have much understanding of coding . I have pdf editor apps that I use to add link but it is tedious. I have to select each element one by one then choose option of adding link and finally scroll to page where I want to redirect.

Comment: I am looking for any app or script that can record the process once of what I did and repeat it required number of times.